# check shipping amount in woocommerce_after_checkout_validation?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I am using a third-party shipping plugin. Sometimes, this plugin somehow acts up, and only charges the client something like 1$.

I'd like to add a sanity check before the order is accepted, that the shipping amount should at least be e.g. 3$.

It seems that I should hook into `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation` to do this there.

But the shipping amount doesn't seem to be in `$_POST` - the only thing of interest is maybe 'shipping_method', but there's no amount to be seen (i just used flat rate as a test):

```
["shipping_method"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "flat_rate:4"
  }
```

How can I look up how much shipping is planned to being charged on the order that has just been submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
global $woocommerce;

$shipping_method = $_POST['shipping_method'][0];
$shipping_amount = $woocommerce->cart->get_shipping_total();
```

Comment: You might want to consider using WC() instead of global $woocommerce, it's a drop-in replacement - so you can just do it like this: WC()->cart->get_shipping_total();